# Unable to run npm install successfully due to karma: none was installed

Tags: json, node.js, gruntjs, npm-install

I have package.json file in which following devDependencies are mentioned:

```
{  "name": "tabs-torico",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "dependencies": {},
  "devDependencies": {
  "grunt": "~0.4.2",
"grunt-angular-templates": "~0.5.1",
"grunt-autoprefixer": "~0.4.0",
"grunt-cli": "~0.1.11",
"grunt-concurrent": "~0.4.1",
"grunt-connect-proxy": "~0.1.7",
"grunt-contrib-clean": "~0.5.0",
"grunt-contrib-compass": "~0.6.0",
"grunt-contrib-concat": "~0.3.0",
"grunt-contrib-connect": "~0.5.0",
"grunt-contrib-copy": "~0.4.1",
"grunt-contrib-cssmin": "~0.7.0",
"grunt-contrib-htmlmin": "~0.1.3",
"grunt-contrib-jshint": "~0.7.1",
"grunt-contrib-uglify": "~0.2.0",
"grunt-contrib-watch": "^0.5.3",
"grunt-karma": "~0.6.2",
"grunt-newer": "~0.5.4",
"grunt-ngmin": "~0.0.2",
"grunt-protractor-runner": "~0.2.1",
"grunt-rev": "~0.1.0",
"grunt-usemin": "~2.0.0",
"jasmine-core": "^2.6.2",
"jshint-stylish": "~0.1.3",
"karma": "^0.10.10",
"karma-chrome-launcher": "^0.1.12",
"karma-html2js-preprocessor": "~0.1.0",
"karma-jasmine": "^0.1.6",
"karma-ng-html2js-preprocessor": "~0.1.0",
"karma-ng-scenario": "~0.1.0",
"karma-requirejs": "~0.2.1",
"karma-script-launcher": "~0.1.0",
"load-grunt-tasks": "~0.2.0",
"phantomjs": "^2.1.7",
"phantomjs-prebuilt": "^2.1.14",
"protractor": "~0.18.1",
"requirejs": "~2.1.10",
"time-grunt": "~0.2.1"
 },
 "engines": {
"node": ">=0.8.0"
},
 "scripts": {
   "test": "grunt test"
}
}
```

Now when I run npm install gives me the following error:

```
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: 
fsevents@github:pipobscure/fseve
nts#7dcdf9fa3f8956610fd6f69f72c67bace2de7138 
(node_modules\chokidar\node_modules
\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for 
fsevents@
0.2.1: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: 
{"os":"win32","arch":"x64"}
)
npm WARN karma@0.10.10 requires a peer of karma-coffee-preprocessor@~0.1.0 
but none was installed.
npm WARN karma@0.10.10 requires a peer of karma-firefox-launcher@~0.1.0 but 
none was installed.
npm WARN karma@0.10.10 requires a peer of karma-phantomjs-launcher@~0.1.0 
but none was installed.
```

Will running npm install install all the dependencies mentioned in the package.json or do I need to install jasmine-core and karma-jasmine separately?

Answer (score 0):

npm install installs all the dependencies specified in your package.json. You should find the in your node_modules folder.

Answer (score 0):

It's the problem with your version of karma.
In the package.json file includes the following line instead of the current line of karma.

```
"karma": "^0.11.14"
```

Also, it is important to note that if you are using karma-chrome-launcher
you need to include that as well in your package.json file as the new version of karma doesn't come with it.

So include the following line as well.

```
"karma-chrome-launcher": "^0.1.2"
```

I hope this will solve your problem.